# How can I catch the SocketTimeoutException "raised" in setSoTimeout()?

Tags: java, sockets, socket-timeout-exception

I am doing socket programming in Java and I am confused by `setSoTimeout()` and its exceptions.

I have a simple `Callable<String>` on the server-side for accepting connections:

```
private Callable<String> waitForConnectionCallable = new Callable<String>() {

    @Override
    public String call() throws IOException {
        if (socket == null) {
            socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }

        socket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        Socket inSocket = socket.accept();
        
        return "CONNECTED";
    }
};
```

And I call and handle it in this way:

```
    try {
        Future<String> connectionFuture = executorService.submit(waitForConnectionCallable);
        String connectionResult = connectionFuture.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        Logs.error(TAG, "No connection received");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, the java doc for `setSoTimeout()` mentions raising a **SocketTimeoutException**, though strangely it is not included in the Throws list:

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a positive timeout value, a call to accept() for this ServerSocket will block for only this amount of time. **If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the ServerSocket is still valid.** A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect.

> Params:
> timeout – the specified timeout, in milliseconds

> Throws:
> SocketException – if there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error
> IllegalArgumentException – if timeout is negative

When I run the program and the connection times out, I get the SocketTimeoutException in the catch block, but in this way:

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out`

**My question is, how can I catch that specific exception?** I can't add it to my caller's catch statement, because I get the compile error of it not being thrown in the method. Also, I can't add to the `call()` method (in the Callable), since *IOException*, a more general exception is already there.

**Additionally:** why SocketTimeoutException is not part of the `setSoTimeout()` signature? Considering it is not a subclass of SocketException.

Comment: You should move your `socket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)` inside the `if (socket == null)` block: calling it once is enough, not each time.

Comment: You have a misconception. `Socket.setSoTImeout()` doesn't throw the exception. `ServerSocket.accept()` and the various `read()` methods of the socket input stream or whatever you wrap around it will throw `SocketTimeoutException` if no connection or data respectively arrives within the timeout period.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing a few things: the  `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown by `socket.accept()`. `socket.setSoTimeout()` can throw an `IOException` (though it's very seldom).

When the `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown inside your `call()` method (by `socket.accept()`), it will be wrapped inside an `ExecutionException`, which is a wrapper-exception. You can then access the original exception by calling `e.getCause()` and handle it accordingly.

EDIT - I'd make a few changes in your code with regard to exception handling. First, I'd use a `Callable<Socket>` instead of `Callable<String>` so you can easily use the socket later on, as you're sure that it's open and connected:

```
private Callable<Socket> waitForConnectionCallable = new Callable<>() {
    @Override
    public Socket call() throws IOException {
        if (socket == null) {
            socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return socket.accept(); // Can throw IOException or SocketTimeoutException
    }
};
```

Then, perform the exception handling in the `waitForConnectionCallable.get()`:

```
try {
        Future<Socket> connectionFuture = executorService.submit(waitForConnectionCallable);
        Socket connectionResult = connectionFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.interrupted();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) { // IOException or SocketTimeoutException
        Throwable t = e.getCause();
        t.printStackTrace();
        if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            Logs.error(TAG, "No connection received");
        } else { // IOException
            Logs.error(TAG, "Error waiting for connection: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Or, you could perform the wait in the `Callable`, but then there might be no point in setting a socket timeout, as you're already using a different thread so you can stay in blocking mode:

```
private Callable<Socket> waitForConnectionCallable = new Callable<>() {
    @Override
    public Socket call() throws IOException {
        if (socket == null) {
            socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        }
        for (;;) { // Until we receive a connection
            try {
                return socket.accept(); // Can throw IOException or SocketTimeoutException
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                // Do something? return null, log, continue, ...
            } // IOException is not caught here and will bubble up in the ExecutionException
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to correct in your observations

> Now, the java doc for setSoTimeout() mentions raising a
> SocketTimeoutException, though strangely it is not included in the
> Throws list

No, it says

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
> With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a call to accept() for
> this ServerSocket will block for only this amount of time. If the
> timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though
> the ServerSocket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to
> entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be >
> 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Which means that, if you set a timeout using the `setSoTimeout()`, a `SocketTimeoutException` will be thrown, if the timeout happens while accepting the connection. So `SocketTimeoutException` is not thrown by `setSoTimeout()`, hence its not in its throws list.

You can catch the timeout exception in the `accept()` method. It throws an `IOException` if something goes wrong in accepting the connection. Timeout can be one of the reasons.

Like below:

```
private Callable<String> waitForConnectionCallable = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws IOException {
            if (socket == null) {
                socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            }

            socket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            try {
                Socket inSocket = socket.accept();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                // do timeout handling...
                return "TIMEOUT";
            }

            return "CONNECTED";
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. I guess I also got confused by the IOException in `accept()` signature and didn't check it was that method throwing the SocketTimeoutException. Also, by "the ServerSocket is still valid", it means the socket is still open and I only need to call accept() again, right?

Comment: yeah, it means the socket is not closed.

Comment: @Mahm00d you can call as many `accept()` as you want on an open `ServerSocket`. If you want to stop accepting connection and close the listening port on your computer, you should close the `ServeSocket`.

Comment: @Mahm00d, also note that `SocketTimeoutException` is a subclass of `IOException` so you might want to catch it *specifically* to handle the common timeout (recoverable), and catch the `IOException` which usually is *not* recoverable.